# Does mod_auth_sspi require Tomcat?

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on

I've tried setting up mod_auth_sspi, but have not managed to get SSO working.

I then realised that this may be because my stack (Uniform Server 8.2) doesn't include Tomcat. I read somewhere some instructions for using mod_auth_sspi that suggested Tomcat was required, but I haven't seen it in the official documentation for mod_auth_sspi nor the Drupal install guide for mod_auth_sspi that I had been working on.

Ideally I'd rather avoid Tomcat as it has a tendency to be a security flaw.

The other option would be to use NTLM, but I don't think NTLM works with Apache on Windows?

Comment: "I've tried setting up mod_auth_sspi, but have not managed to get SSO working." - What have you actually done? How did it work out, and what were you expecting?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.

Largely followed these instructions on Drupal: https://drupal.org/node/1371478

This has all worked to some extent. When I go to the Drupal login I can login using Active Directory credentials. It then reads the AD and signs the user in using those credentials even if they do not exist on the Drupal site.

However it is not able to read the AD credentials from the user's machine and log in with these, so there is no SSO.

I have more info on this error in a separate post: http://serverfault.com/questions/570396/configuring-mod-auth-sspi-to-find-remote-user